# MySQL copy multiple row-entries to another position

Tags: mysql, copy, sql-update, row

I want to copy a big amount of values from a specific row and specific date to the same row, but another date. I have tried it with the SQL UPDATE SET function and two different tables, but the SET will only use the first value and copy it to the right date-columns.

At this picture you see the results:
[image: picture]

And this is one of the queries I tried:

```
UPDATE Test_tab t
SET t.testValue = 
    (SELECT testValue
    FROM Test_tab 
    WHERE testDate > '2015-10-01' AND testDate < '2015-10-31'
        LIMIT 1)
WHERE t.testDate  > '2015-11-01' AND t.testDate  < '2015-11-31'
```

Comment: I'm unclear - do you want an update or an insert!?!?

Comment: I want an update. I thought that would be easy, to move an old row-section to a new row-section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE your_proc()
BEGIN 
 DECLARE cont INTEGER; 
 SET cont = 0;
 SET max = SELECT count(*) FROM test_tab;
  WHILE cont < max DO 
   UPDATE Test_tab t SET t.testValue =(SELECT testValue FROM Test_tab WHERE testDate >'2015-10-01' AND testDate <'2015-10-31'
   LIMIT cont, 1) WHERE t.testDate > '2015-11-01' AND t.testDate < '2015-11-31'
   SET cont = cont + 1; 
  END WHILE; 
END;
```

Comment: I don´t understand why the subquery returns more than 1 row? I have selected only the row 'testValue'!?
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Check now, its modified